# Problem with national characters using the PHP function sybase_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, charset

I am using PHP function sybase_connect to connect to mssql database and retrieave data like this:

```
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "cp1257");
$mssql->query("EXEC AuthLoginList");
while($mssql->get_row()){
  echo $mssql->f('id')." ".$mssql->f('name')." ".$mssql->f('surname')."<br>";
}
```

[image]

However, national symbols are incorrectly extracted. Questionnaires appear in their place:
[image]

Database version is  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)

The following encodings are used for text fields:

[image]

[image]

It doesn't matter what encoding you use. The result is always the same. Question marks are provided instead of national symbols. Ex:

```
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "cp1257");
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "iso-8859-1");
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "utf8");
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "utf-8"); 
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "iso_1");
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "windows-1257");
$mssql=sybase_connect($Host, $User, $Password, "UNICODE");
```

Maybe someone could give me advice on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Curious why you're using a sybase library to connect to SQL Server, have you tried using a modern SQL Server library? Is the PHP file itself stored as UTF-8 or ...? What is the `default_charset` setting? Why are you using some Latvian and some Lithuanian?

Comment: i think you can use PDO to connect to mssql

Comment: You probably could use PDO, @Jerson , but then you could just use the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long reading of the TDS protocol documentation, I found a solution:

```
> export LANG lt_LT
```

By setting the environment variable LANG in this way, the MSSQL database in my nevironment obtains the correct encoding ISO-8859-13.

[image]